# Missing C/C++ Build settings under project properties of Eclipse ADT

Tags: windows-7-x64, eclipse-adt

Hi Does anyone know why I don't have the C/C++ Build settings and the C/C++ General setting under my project properties on ADT?

[image]

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm running into the same issue in Linux with the OpenCV4Android library.

Comment: you click on `Builders` add a new builder and locate your ndk-build file which is on your ndk root directory , point the working directory to your OpenCV4Android library.

Comment: @Pwnna did it work for you?

Answer (score 3):

You can press CTRL+N and then choose "Convert to C/C++ project".
More here: http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/

Comment: This worked for me. Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a) on Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: Works for me with Eclipse 4.11 on Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, it is due to an overlap with another project. In another word, I tried to create a project based on an existing one that was created before (but I manually erase the .cproject, .project and .settings/ etc.)